# Finding all smaller digits for every entry in the array towards the right

Tags: python, algorithm

The array contains digits and it is unsorted. Its length could be as big as 120000. I need to count the smaller numbers to the right of each digit.

This is a coding challenge on Codewars which requires a specific code efficency to be completed (Solve X amount in Y time).
https://www.codewars.com/kata/56a1c63f3bc6827e13000006/train/python

Example:

```
100, 10, 10, 10, 10]should return 4, 0, 0, 0, 0

1, 2, 3             should return 0, 0, 0

1, 2, 0             should return 1, 1, 0

1, 2, 1             should return 0, 1, 0
```

My current approach is to sort the array and then do a binary search inside that array for the current number. Afterwards I skip over the possible duplicates of this number and search for the next smaller number and return the amount of all leftover entities.
I then remove the just used number out of the sorted array.

My question is mostly about using a fast approach to this problem, since the time needed with my program takes too long.

```
def smaller(arr):
    sorted_arr = sorted(arr)
    lenght = len(arr)
    for i in range(lenght):
        pos = binary_search(sorted_arr, arr[i])
        while sorted_arr[pos] == sorted_arr[pos-1] and pos-1>=0:
            pos -= 1
        arr[i] = pos
        sorted_arr.pop(pos)
    return arr

def binary_search(arr, x):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    mid = 0
    while low <= high:
        mid = (high + low) // 2
        if arr[mid] < x:
            low = mid + 1
        elif arr[mid] > x:
            high = mid-1
        else:
            return mid
    return -1
```

Comment: In the problem descriptions hyperlinked, I find *numbers* instead of *digits*. (*Digits* would allow to use *counting*.)

Comment: (There is no `lenght`.)

Comment: (Consider processing array elements right-to-left.)

Comment: @Felix, you accepted vnp's answer, probably you created a solution with vnp's hints. Could you post this solution as an answer to your own question (with of course credits to vnp) for future readers of this question?

Comment: @JanKuiken Yes I indeed created a solution for the problem. However I think it would be very unpolite regarding the author of the question(kata) on codewars, since this is supposed to be a level 3 exercise (level 1 being the hardest and level 8 being the lowest) and therefore hard to solve without an explicit solution online. Anyone being good enough to solve a leve 3 exercise, reading my code and reading the accepted solution should be able to reproduce my solution with a bit of thinking :)

Comment: @Felix, ok, i am not aware of the policies on codewars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't reinvent the wheel. Python has a [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module; use `bisect_left`.
- Popping an arbitrary element from a list has a linear time complexity, which drives the total time complexity of your solution to quadratic. Unfortunately you have to reconsider an algorithm.
- The problem is very similar to counting inversions. The only difference is that you are interested not in a total amount of inversions, but in a per-element ones. This observation suggests yet another variation on a merge sort theme. I don't want to spell out the algorithm. As a hint, merge sort `value, count` tuples.